# I'm not able to detect the problem while compiling

Tags: c

[I'm writing first program in C Language but I'm unable to compile it. Please help me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd1A4.png)

Comment: Post your code (not a picture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the file. Press CTRL + S. You can also see you haven't saved it at the blue "1" on the left side of your VS Code sidebar. If you don't save it, you're just trying to compile an empty file.

Comment: It really worked!!!!!!!!! Now I gained confidence to work... Thanks a lot